# Font color returns Color.Empty instead of Color.White using Epplus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

[image]

This is my test setup, as can be seen the font color is white with some characters in red.
When I read it with C# Epplus, I get resulting color as `Color.Empty`.
Code as under:

```
    ExcelWorksheet ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    int colCount = ws.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
    int rowCount = ws.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row coun

    // per line
    for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++) {
        for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++) {
            ExcelRange cell = ws.Cells[row, col];

            // get rich text section info
            for (int r = 0; r < cell.RichText.Count; r++) {
                ExcelRichText richText = cell.RichText[r];

                Color rColor = richText.Color; // This shows Color.Empty

            }   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further checks it was found that the issue is with `Theme Color`.
Excel has 2 sets of colors in its picker, `Theme` and `Standard`, if we only work with `Standard colors` EPPlus doesn't have a problem and **correctly** detects it.